# Add to cart button with quentity filed under image woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add `add to cart button with quantity` filed under image in single product page. i have tried many code but not luck. one code which work but issue is that quantity not adding properly. i add below code `my-theme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php` before `do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );` hook.

```
if ( ! is_shop() && ! is_product_taxonomy() ) {
    $quantity_field = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
        'input_name'  => 'product_id',
        'input_value' => ! empty( $product->cart_item['quantity'] ) ? $product->cart_item['quantity'] : 1,
        'max_value'   => $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity(),
        'min_value'   => 0,
    ), $product, false );

    $quantity_field = str_replace( array( '<div class="quantity">', "</div>" ), '', $quantity_field );
    echo str_replace( '<input ', '<input style="max-width: 70px" ', $quantity_field );
}

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

[image]

Comment: you can share your design so we can easy understanding.

Comment: Please now you can see image please @MansukhKhandhar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi add this hook in your function file.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30 );
```

display as like default WC
http://screencast.com/t/u8giinLfKmzt

Comment: You are a Great  :)  @MansukhKhandhar